# Force eviction of sliding event windows for processing (historical streams) on Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Currently, I am using Flink to conduct research on stream processing engines. For my study, I work with historical streams, which consist of tuples of the following form:

`event_time, attribute_1, ..., attribute_X`

where `event_time` is used as `TimeCharacteristic.EventTime` during processing. Furthermore, I push my datasets into the processing topology, by either: (i) creating in-memory structures, or (ii) by reading the CSV files themselves.

Unfortunately, I have noticed that even if enough tuples have arrived in a window operator that complete a full window, that window is not pushed downstream for processing. As a result, the performance significantly drops and many times I have an `OutOfMemoryError` exception (with large historical streams).

To illustrate a typical use-case, I present the following example:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
env.setParallelism(1);
env.setMaxParallelism(1);
List<Tuple2<Long, Integer>> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(new Tuple2<>(1L, 11));
    l.add(new Tuple2<>(2L, 22));
    l.add(new Tuple2<>(3L, 33));
    l.add(new Tuple2<>(4L, 44));
    l.add(new Tuple2<>(5L, 55));
    DataStream<Tuple2<Long, Integer>> stream = env.fromCollection(l);
    stream.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Tuple2<Long, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Tuple2<Long, Integer> t) {
                return t.f0;
            }
        })
        .windowAll(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2), 
                Time.milliseconds(1)))
        .sum(1)
        .print();
    env.execute();
```

According to `l`'s contents, I need to have the following windowed results:

- [0, 2) Sum: 11
- [1, 3) Sum: 33
- [2, 4) Sum: 55
- [3, 5) Sum: 77
- [4, 6) Sum: 99
- [5, 7) Sum: 55

Each list item can be read as [start-timestamp, end-timestamp), Sum: X.

I expect Flink to produce a windowed result every time a tuple with a timestamp beyond the end-timestamp of an open window appears. For instance, I expect the summation for window [1, 3) to be produced when the tuple with timestamp `4L` is fed into the window operator. However, the processing initiates when all the tuples from `l` are pushed into the stream's topology. The same thing happens when I work with larger historical streams, which results in degraded performance (or even depleting memory).

**Question:** How can I force Flink to push windows downstream for processing by the time a window is complete?

I believe that for `SlidingEventTimeWindows` the eviction of a window is triggered with watermarks. If the previous is true, how can I write my topologies so that they trigger windows by the time a tuple with a later timestamp arrives?

Thank you

Comment: Is your source actually a stream, or are you always reading it into memory first? In your example, the full input is going to be read in fromCollection

Comment: Usually it's read from a CSV file. The example I posted is to present an easy to follow example of what is happening inside Flink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AscendingTimestampExtractor` uses the periodic watermarking strategy, in which Flink will call the `getCurrentWatermark()` method every n milliseconds, where n is the [autowatermarkinterval](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/ExecutionConfig.html#setAutoWatermarkInterval).

The default interval is 200 milliseconds, which is very long compared to the size of your windows. However, they aren't directly comparable -- the 200 msec is measured in processing time, not event time. Nevertheless, I suspect that if you haven't changed this configuration setting, then a lot of windows are created before the first watermark is emitted, which I think explains what you are seeing.

You could reduce the auto-watermarking interval (perhaps to 1 millisecond). Or you could implement an [AssignerWithPunctuatedWatermarks](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#with-punctuated-watermarks), which will give you more control.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and I will definitely try it. However, on larger datasets (~2-4 GBs) I have a similar behavior. Even though ingress of those tuples takes much more than 200 msec, the processing is postponed until all tuples are ingested. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: When working with larger datasets, what is the data source? Kafka, filesystem, ... ?

Comment: Usually CSV files stored on a file system. I work mostly with Historical streams.